# selectInput with RenderUI doesn't show all choices

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on a shiny app with dynamic selectInput created with renderUI.
Here is the code in server.R:

```
  output$list_station<- renderUI({
   
    choix_ce <- input$choice_of_ce
    
    postes <- map_consos_enedis %>% 
      filter(Region == choix_ce) %>% 
      select(station)
    
    selectInput(inputId = "choice_of_station",
                label = "Choix du poste",
                choices = as.list(postes),
                selected = postes[1],
                multiple = FALSE)
  })
```

It works almost fine... only if *postes* returns 2 or more elements. If *postes* returns 1 element, the dropdown only contains *station* which is the variable name of *postes* and I don't understand why.

Comment: could you provide an example of dput(postes) to help understand what is happening?

Comment: Sure! Here dput(postes) if _postes_ contains 1 element:  structure(list(station = "AUCUN"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")). And with 2 or more elements (all elements not show): structure(list(station = c("A.DUCP3", "A.OTHP3", "ABBENP3", "ABBENP3", [........], "VOUJEP3", "VOUJEP3", "WADONP3", "WALDIP3", "WALDIP3")), row.names = c(NA, 
-603L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `postes$station` as `choices` argument, instead of `as.list(postes)`:

```
selectInput(inputId = "choice_of_station",
            label = "Choix du poste",
            choices = postes$station,
            selected = postes$station[1],
            multiple = FALSE)
```

Reason for this that `choices` argument to `selectInput` can either take as argument :

1. a `list`
2. a named `list`
3. a named `list` with groups, see [doc](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/selectInput.html).

By using `postes$station`, the `postes` dataframe is reduced to a simple character vector without name, ie option 1), which gives the output you expect.

When you only have 1 row in `postes`, `as.list(postes)` becomes a named list `list(station='AUCUN')` which makes `selectInput` use option 2, ie show name `station` but select value `'AUCUN'` and is the reason for your question.

When you have many rows in `postes`, `as.list(postes)` becomes a named list
with groups which makes `selectInput` use option 3.

Comment: I'm modifying the reason : I found the real one ;) - give me 3 minutes